# What are some effective ways to build & run an SRPM without installing it?

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am on Fedora 31 and I do software development. I need to work with code in many **source** RPM packages for relatively short periods of time. For this reason, I'd like to simply build the package, but not actually perform the "install" step most of the time.

Is there a way to do this using RPM yum or DNF? To clarify, I would like to build the project as specified in the specfile, in order to have running binaries, but not "install" it; that is, I do not want the built files to be actually copied into the system's filesystem structure.

Comment: Seems to me that `rpmbuild -bc` would build ("make") the binaries but stop short of the installation. Does that sound like what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Building RPMs should not install any of the resulting binaries onto your system (at least I have never observed that behavior using `rpmbuild`).  Though it does normally require installing the SRPM and any build dependencies required to build the package.

If your intention is to avoid having to install SRPM packages into your system to get the `SOURCES` and `SPEC` of each project, I would recommend [`mock` from the RPM people](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock).  It should be available in the main Fedora repositories: `dnf install mock`

`mock` is a wrapper around `rpmbuild` that utilizes chroots to build RPMs directly from SRPMs.  This has the bonus benefit of not having to install SRPMs or any build dependencies on your main system since they are installed inside the chroot.

It can also build SRPMs directly from local directories or source control.

Answer (score 1):

the `%install` step when building an `rpm` doesn't actually **install** the binaries on your system, it installs the binaries in the RPM_BUILD_ROOT, that is justs one of the rpm build steps.

Your workflow could look like this:

- `rpm -i *.src.rpm` : install the source rpm. This will just unpack the src.rpm and put the source files, spec file etc under `~/rpmbuild`.
- You can then `cd ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/` where you will find the spec file to build the `rpm` files.
- [optionally] you can do some modifications to the sources, spec file etc
- now build the `rpm` packages using `rpmbuild -ba the.spec`

This is explained here in more detail: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/04/20/working-with-source-rpms/.

**NOTE**: if you just want to rebuild a source rpm, without any changes, you can always try `rpmbuild --rebuild the.src.rpm`